# How to Set up direct sign-in for multi-tenant Azure Active Directory using Custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I use Azure Ad b2c to authenticate users, using custom policy. I use this document to add login with Azure AD (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c -custom-policy).

I use this document to configure the iframe embedding:

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

But when I embed login page in ASP NetMVC page, and use login with Azure AD, it gives error:

[image]

My SignSignup

```
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="CustomSignUpSignIn" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <JourneyFraming Enabled="true" Sources="https://test.dynatex.io https://testsquid.dynatex.io/" />
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
```

My B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS.xml

```
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <Domain>onmicrosoft.com</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Common AAD</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AADCommon-OpenIdConnect">
          <DisplayName>Multi-Tenant Azure Ad</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ProviderName">https://login.microsoftonline.com</Item>
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
            <!-- Update the Client ID below to the Application ID -->
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid profile email</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
            <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id">9...</Item>
            <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com</Item>
            <!-- <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</Item> -->
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_msa" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="loginHint" PartnerClaimType="login_hint" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="roles" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot perform federated logon with the "Embedded UI", since all external IdPs will block being displayed in the iframe.

For these scenarios, you need to redirect the user. One way is:

1. In the Sign In policy, replace the external links to point back to your app, eg `myapp.com/signin?domain_hint=azureAD`
2. Then, your app needs to redirect the user via AAD B2C policy like the normal flow, and pass a domain_hint parameter such that the user is autoamtically directed to the IdP they had selected in 1.

Comment: @ how can I do that, any example